# Str to double in matlab

Tags: matlab, char, cell

I have a variable lets say x, that contain ***chars*** as follow :

```
123123213
343423434
454545455
....
```

If i do :

```
x(1) = 1 
x(1,1:9) = 123123213
```

I want to be able to get when i write :

```
x(1)=123123213
```

I tried doing:

```
s=[cellstr(x)];
t=[str2double(s)];
```

Then i got "t" something like that :

```
ans =

1.0e+020 *

   1.1352
   1.1006
   1.0835
   ....
```

Image explaining :

http://i60.tinypic.com/2vv8jo6.png
http://i60.tinypic.com/2dbs3t3.png

If it helps im using **matlab 7.12** .

Comment: Just to be clear - you want the result to be `doubles` or `chars`?

Comment: i want them integers/doubles.

Comment: why would anyone down vote the question ???? what wrong ??? at least explain ????? i've explained a lot , provided pictures details its about programming , all what this site requires .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe str2num:

```
x = ['123123123';'343423434';'454545455']

x_num = str2num(x);

x_num(1)

ans =

   123123123
```

Comment: @saeedhardan Yes, it did. Use `format long` to change the way the numbers are displayed. your method with `str2double` is equally valid.

Comment: tried it , now it prints longer digits   1.0e+020 *

   1.094991084181885

Comment: Well, that is the number. It is too large to display as an integer, MATLAB can only display it this way. If you have the Symbolic Toolbox, you can try using `vpa`.